# Conditional Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a lambda expression that currently looks like this:

```
item => Reports.Add(item)
```

I want to modify it such that it is conditional, and basically checks that Reports.Contains(item) returns false, then performs the Reports.Add(item) action.  Is this possible to do using lambda all on one line?

Chris

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Action<ItemType> action = item => { if(!Reports.Contains(item)) Reports.Add(item);};
```

That should do, but it depends on how you define 'one line', really.

Answer (score 5):

alternative to Ani's suggestion: make Reports a HashSet.

Comment: Agreed.  It sounds like a different data structure may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can separate multiple lines in your lambda with semicolons.